# postgresql: Adding/updating a key with array value to json column

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb, jsonb-array-elements

I have a column "data" with datatype json that may be empty `{ }` or may contain some keys already:
`{ "category": "alpha", "verified": true }`
I want to have a `notes` key which will be a text array. If it doesn't exist, an `UPDATE` query should create it with the text provided, otherwise it shall add to it (index position doesn't matter while appending).

There will always be a single note to be added to the `notes` key.

Currently, I am doing it as follows:

```
SELECT data::jsonb ? 'notes' FROM my_table WHERE id = 1;
```

If it is false, I create the key and provide the first value:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET data = jsonb_set(coalesce(data::jsonb,'{}'), '{notes}', '["Add"]'::jsonb)
WHERE id = 1;
```

If it exists, I append to the same array:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET data = jsonb_set(data::jsonb, array['notes'], (data->'notes')::jsonb || '["Update"]'::jsonb)
WHERE id = 1;
```

Can this be done in a single operation? I eventually will be writing a function that will update other columns of this table and adding/updating notes as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is easily as done single operation. Basically just use your first query as a `case` clause. Insert or append `notes:` based on the result. (see [demo here][1]).

```
update my_table 
   set data = case when data::jsonb ? 'notes' 
                   then jsonb_set(data::jsonb, array['notes'], (data->'notes')::jsonb || '["Update"]'::jsonb)
                   else jsonb_set(coalesce(data::jsonb,'{}'), '{notes}', '["Add"]'::jsonb)
              end   
 where id ...;
```

This of course presupposes the `id`(s) in question exist and the `data` column is itself not null (that is different that from an empty Json).
[1]: https://dbfiddle.uk/_TVKAm9a